# What Node Module provides a CLI prompt?

Tags: node.js, npm, prompt, read-eval-print-loop

I have been searching far and wide for a node module that provides a REPL-like CLI prompt interface for a Node app.

What I am looking for is kind of a hybrid between [inquirer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inquirer) or [prompt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompt), and [commander](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander#coercion).

Node provides a [built-in REPL module](http://derickbailey.com/2014/07/02/build-your-own-app-specific-repl-for-your-nodejs-app/), however this just exposes the raw javascript of your application. I want to built a virtual interface for an application.

Example, supposing you run `node server.js`, you would get a prompt:

```
server:~$
```

This would behave like a basic unix prompt, in your own virtual context. Pressing `enter`:

```
server:~$
server:~$
```

Or `help`:

```
server:~$ help

Commands:

debug [setting]   Enables or disables debugging.
show stats        Displays live stats for your web server.

server:~$
```

And you could execute custom commands:

```
server:~$ debug on -v 7
Debugging turned on with a verbosity of 7
... live logging ...
```

Any idea of what NPM modules handle this?

---

#### Update 9 months later

Due to nothing matching my needs, I ended up building and publishing [Vorpal](https://github.com/dthree/vorpal), a framework for building Interactive CLIs in Node.

Comment: http://derickbailey.com/2014/07/02/build-your-own-app-specific-repl-for-your-nodejs-app/

Answer (score 4):

You could use the standard REPL module and plug in a custom command evaluator. The "up arrow to repeat commands" and such is already baked into the repl module, so you don't need to worry about that.

For example, here's a crappily implemented evaluator that does the things you've described in your question:

```
var repl = require("repl");

var cmds = {
    "help" : function(input, context) { 
        return "debug [setting]   Enables or disables debugging..." 
    },
    "debug" : function(input, context) {
        var args = input.split(/\s+/).slice(1);

        var onoff = args[0];
        var verbosity = args[2];

        return "Debugging turned " + onoff + " with a verbosity of " + verbosity;
    },
    "exit": function(input, context) {
        process.exit();
    },
    "default" : function(input, context) { 
        return "Command not understood";
    }
};

function eval(input, context, filename, callback) {
    var cmd = input.split(/\s+/)[0];
    var result = (cmds[cmd] || cmds["default"])(input, context);
    callback(null, result);
}

repl.start({
    prompt: "server:~$ ",
    eval: eval
});
```

Please note the focus of the demo here is how to implement a custom REPL; there are obviously better ways to implement the evaluator than whitespace splitting and a hash of functions, but how you implement the command evaluator depends on what your application is supposed to do

Answer (score 1):

There is a [node-shell](https://github.com/wdavidw/node-shell) available, see also the [home page](http://www.adaltas.com/projects/node-shell/).

Features from the home page are:

*Shell brings a Connect inspired API, Express inspired routing, and other similar functionality to console based applications.*

- *Run both in shell mode and command mode*
- *First class citizen for console application (arrows, ctrl-a, ctrl-u,…)*
- *User friendly with history, help messages and many other plugings*
- *Foundation to structure and build complex based applications*
- *Command matching, parameters and advanced functionnalities found in Express routing*
- *Flexible architecture based on middlewares for plugin creation and routing enhancement*
- *Familiar API for those of us using Connect or Express*
- *Predifined commands through plugins for Redis, HTTP servers, Cloud9, CoffeeScript, …*

You find a basic reddis client example on the homepage which comes with command completion and history.

Comment: That's a really good one - hadn't seen that before. +1

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're actually looking for the [`readline`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html) module, which powers the `repl` module.

Comment: True, but looking for something a little more developed.